# Formsubmit.co form not working in reactapp

Tags: reactjs, forms, form-submit

I added formsubmit service to my email form on my react application simple personal website. but it does not seem to be working. It does nothing. Does the extra javascript in there mess with the formsubmit service? I actually put my real email in just changed it for this post.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './styles.contactform.css';


function ContactForm() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(name, email, message)
        setName('') 
        setEmail('')
        setMessage('')       

    }


    return (
        <div className="contact-container">
            <form className="contact-form" action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail@email.com" method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://notmicahclark.herokuapp.com/"/>
                <input type="text" value={name} id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name..." onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} required/>
                <input type="email" value={email} id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} required/>
                <img className="letter-img"  src="contact_form_imagepng.png" alt="Mail Letter"/>
                <input id="message" value={message} name="message" placeholder="Your message..." onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}/>
                <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` *explicitly* prevents the form action, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault.

Answer (score 3):

To overcome this issue, you can use the **AJAX form** feature provided by FormSubmit.

According to their documentation:

> You can easily submit the form using AJAX without ever having your
> users leave the page. — this even works cross-origin.

Please refer to their documentation about AJAX forms (sample code snippets are available): https://formsubmit.co/ajax-documentation

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code. The problem is that you are both using the form's HTML *action* field, and at the same time using your own *method* for form submission. Remove the *action=...* call and instead write this in your *handleSubmit* method.

```
fetch('https://formsubmit.co/ajax/myemail@email.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(event.target))),
    })
```

Should work like a charm. Add *then* and *catch* statements to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

For AJAX request you can do this way:

1. Delete the `action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail@email.com" method="POST"` form element
2. you could use their AJAX documentation

`

```
fetch("https://formsubmit.co/ajax/your@email.com", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        message: message,
        email: email

    })
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

`

This way you could perform customize success, error message, or inputs invalidation: